# PHP cURL can't create XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to get the XML file from an URL.
But I get only the text from the file, without syntax.

My Code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://services.mobile.de/search-api/search?country=DE&sort.field=makeModel&sort.order=ASCENDING');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode("username:password"), 'Accept: 
    application/xml'));
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(curl_exec($ch));//line 14
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($xml);
```

My Output:

```
....sensorsBlackEuro5PetrolManual gearboxAutomatic air conditioningUsed vehicle150.90525114.812090CarSmall CarVolkswagenPoloCentral lockingElectric windowsImmobilizerPower Assisted SteeringABSESPFull Service HistoryElectric side mirrorOn-board computerCD playerTuner/radioIsofix (child seat anchor points)Parking sensor

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 14

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 14

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php(14): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('1') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test.php on line 14
```

Update:

I get now the right string in the browser with this:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r(curl_exec($ch), true));
echo '</pre>';
```

But when i try to use:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($re);
print_r($sxe);
```

I only get this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Comment: when you open xml url on browser, can you see valid xml or not?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the API returns XML? What happens if you send the request from the command line using curl?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an XML file from your request?  What does `$response = curl_exec($ch); echo htmlspecialchars($response);` show you?

Comment: @hakkikonu I get the right XML over the browser.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think so. https://services.mobile.de/manual/search-api.html

Comment: @RocketHazmat The same thing. I get only the text from the XML file, all the "<search:search-result xmlns:seller=" and so on is missing.

Comment: can you try without Accept header?

Comment: A userid/password is required to access the API. I know the doc says it returns can but unless you see it don't believe it.

Comment: @hakkikonu It is already only the basic html head and body and the code above.

Comment: @JimGarrison The API returns the right XML in the browser.

Comment: @JimGarrison 
I get these from the browser:
[link](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfoto4ak25e30nu.png)
a normal xml...
And from my php Code:
[link](http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfotorp7bvzmxia.png)
How can that be?

Comment: Maybe the server returns something different based on the `User-Agent` header?

Comment: I can read the right output with echo htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch)); 
I get a perfekt xml string. But I can't use implexml_load_string on this. Then I get Start tag expected, '<' not found.

Answer (score 1):

`new SimpleXMLElement()` with only one argument expects XML ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php)) and `curl_exec($ch)` returns `true` or `false` by default ([manual](http://php.net/curl_exec)). Thus it's clear why this won't work:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(curl_exec($ch));//line 14
```

You probably want to follow the tip at curl_exec manual page:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, **if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success**, FALSE on failure.

... but you'll still need to verify that it isn't `false`. If you omit error checking your code will fail randomly now and then.

Comment: with curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); i get only SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Comment: Don't process the response through several layers of code before even knowing if it's good. Start by e.g. var_dump().

Comment: The problem is that curl returns only a List of stings from the original xml file. The XML syntax ist missing.

Comment: Did you by chance display the XML tags inside an HTML document and then see it all rendered through the browser? If so, you have to use the "View Source" menu item.

Comment: Great, thanks! The xml was hidden by the browser.
I can see it with echo htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch));
But 
  $xml = $xml = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch)) or die("ERROR");
    print_r($xml)
returns still "ERROR" (Start tag expected, '<' not found). What can I do solve the problem?

Comment: It can't be valid XML if SimpleXML doesn't recognise it as such. Save it to a file and pass it though an XML validator (you can find online validators in Google or use a browser as such).

Comment: I test the output of echo htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch)); with this validator [link](http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidate) and i get allways "Valid XML!" But print_r(simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch))); give me every time "SimpleXMLElement Object ( )"

Comment: Then it's finally fixed? What was the issue?

Comment: No, it isn't fixed. I have now a correct XML string, but i can't convert it into XML. When I use simplexml_load_string($re); it returns me a empty XML. When I use simplexml_load_string($re) or die("Error"); it returns me "Error".

Comment: Sorry but you're giving contradictory information all the time, e.g. that `simplexml_load_string()` creates an object or fails every time. Also, since the manual says **This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE** you cannot trust `or die()`.

Comment: This is my current code: [link](http://pastebin.com/r9A43NLk)

My output is only "SimpleXMLElement Object ( )".
How is that possible? It throws no error but the Object is empty.

Comment: 1) SimpleXML objects are virtual, their properties are generated on-the-fly whenever you refer to them thus `print_r()` will not display the complete XML 2) That code you link looks fairly unrelated to this question. Reading namespaced XML can be tricky.

Comment: Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: Yes, of course, Your question is about loading XML via Curl. An answer that explains something entirely different is not going to help anyone.